# Can I have an office in my basement without egress?

Tags: basement, basement-refinishing

I'm looking to create an office space in my basement.  I live in a townhouse attached to 2 other units.  In the basement we currently have smalls windows near the ceiling.

From what I've read, it sounds like I need to add a second means of egress.  The only way into the basement right now is the main interior stairs.

The problem is that if I need to add a second means of egress, I need to go through the association.  I am pretty sure that they wont let me cut a hole in the foundation in order to add egress.

Are there any alternatives to adding egress?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to contact your local building department to be sure, but it's very likely that they'll require a second means of egress. They might also have localized information, on ways others in your area have dealt with the problem. It's not likely that you're the only person in your area that's wanted to add living space to their basement.

> ## International Residential Code 2012
>
> ### Chapter 3 Building Planning
>
> #### Section 310 Emergency Escape and Rescue Openings
>
> **R310.1 Emergency escape and rescue required.**
> Basements, habitable attics and every sleeping room shall have at least one operable emergency escape and rescue opening. Where basements contain one or more sleeping rooms, emergency egress and rescue openings shall be required in each sleeping room...
> ...Emergency escape and rescue openings shall open directly into a public way, or to a yard or court that opens to a public way.
>
> ***Exception:** Basements used only to house mechanical equipment and not exceeding total floor area of 200 square feet (18.58 m2).*

Based on this code, as soon as a basement is used for more than housing mechanical equipment, egress is required. Though I think most places allow storage and such, and only get picky when a *habitable* space is added to the basement.

According to the IRC, habitable spaces include any space used for living, sleeping, eating, or cooking.  Non-habitable spaces include bathrooms, toilet rooms, closets, halls, storage and utility spaces, and any similar spaces.

According to [Mass.gov](http://www.mass.gov/eopss/consumer-prot-and-bus-lic/license-type/csl/8th-edition-residential-code.html), Massachusetts follows International Residential Code 2009 with some amendments. Though it doesn't appear that there are any amendments to the section quoted above.

Comment: Wait a minute, my understanding (and my city's permitting office's) is that an office doesn't require a second method of egress, unlike a bedroom where you can actually sleep in. Offices are okay with just a door. Even the code you mention above specifically only discusses bedroom egress, and a basement egress. No mention of habitable living space.

Comment: This is not true for any basement I have remodeled.  Unless we are going to specifically officially call something a bedroom, then you only need one method.  Great to have two but I have finished a LOT of basements that were signed off by the city with no secondary egress (just stairs and common basement windows).

Comment: It sounds like this might be a gray area in practice.  I guess I will need to speak with the town inspector to see what they think in my case.

Comment: @DMoore Codes vary from place to place, that's why I started by saying that the OP should contact their building department. In my area if there's any type of habitable space in a basement, two escape routes are required.

Comment: @alt An office *is* different than a bedroom. A bedroom must have an escape route directly from the bedroom,  whereas an office can use a common escape route.

Comment: "Check with local code" is really the only answer we can give online. But yes, in my experience (which is only local to one area and one set of code), what triggered an egress window in a sub-level room was whether or not it had a built in closet. If it did, then it was flagges as a potential bedroom (now or in the future) and, as such, needed egress. An office--as long as there were no closet--wouldn't trigger that.

Comment: Sorry I left out the last sentence in that code section. Notice that it requires the emergency escape route to open to the "*outside*". Which is why the stairway leading into your house does not count.

Comment: @alt It's not a second method of egress, it's an emergency escape route (which must go outside).

Comment: @Tester101, yep. As I read it (and as my approved basement permits state), only bedrooms need separate egress options to the outside, other than a door to the inside (which, I'm assuming, is optional). The basement itself also needs an outside egress, of course, in addition to any sleeping area's egress. An office, or a movie room, by itself won't, unless all egress options are taken up by bedrooms, in which case you somehow need to make one.

Comment: @alt I'm confused... I think the two similar, yet different terms are confusing things.  An empty basement requires a form of egress, because without it you can't get in and out. If the basement has "*habitable*" space, it requires a form of egress **and** an emergency escape route.  If the egress leads "*outside*", it fulfills both requirements.  If you have bedrooms in a basement, you need an emergency escape route *in* **each** bedroom. (Continued).

Comment: (Continued). I'm sure some jurisdictions are less strict, and don't require an emergency escape route. My answer is based on International Residential Code, not local codes for every jurisdiction.

Comment: @Tester101, a basement and sleeping areas both need two means of egress, each. Your stairs and an egress window will suffice for the basement and all its unenclosed habitable spots in their entirety, while each sleeping area can make do with a door and an egress window, which are not the same as those you would use for the basement.

Comment: @alt - Just FYI - I have finished basements in at least 6 states.  If you want an official bedroom your windows must meet a certain local ordinance for emergency entrance plus you must have a functioning staircase.  In all other cases just a functioning staircase.   I have never had a conversation about creating an egress other than us needing to count something as a bedroom - but there is more to it than that in most states - most require a walk out on that floor.